# 'undefined' object property

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { ArtistService } from './../../services/artist.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-form',
  templateUrl: './profile-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-form.component.css']
})
export class ProfileFormComponent implements OnInit {
  artists: any[];
  songs: any[];
  profile: any = {};

  constructor(private artistService: ArtistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.artistService.getArtists().subscribe(artists =>
      this.artists = artists);
  }

  onArtistChange(){
    var selectedArtist = this.artists.find(a => a.id == this.profile.artist);
    this.songs = selectedArtist.songs;
  }
}
```

In these lines produces errors about properties

```
artists: any[];
songs: any[];
```

How to fix that?
if I fix the error, then the program doesnt run

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the exact message, if possible screenshot of error message

Comment: initialize it `artists: any[]=[]`;

Comment: Maybe you have some linting rules that are messing up with your property declaration ? Can you test that `artists: any[] = [];` and `songs: any[] = [];`

Comment: @mickdev Yep! Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the IDE will fix the problem for you by click in one of those "Add..." items in the menu. @Vikas has the right idea; initialize the property to an empty array. Please do be more explicit when saying things like "then the program doesnt run" -- do you mean an error occurs? What error? Or does it just not compile? What options have you specified in your tsconfig.json?